# Advantages of p-toluenesulfonic acid over sulfuric acid in the formation of acetals

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request, nucleophilic-substitution, catalysis, organocatalysis

I am currently working on an undergraduate experiment to form a cyclic acetal.
We were asked to use *p*-toluenesulfonic acid as a catalyst rather than sulfuric acid.
This seems to be common practice when forming an acetal, but the reasons given are not satisfactory to me.

Being a solid, it is more easy to handle, I can understand that. But another reason given is that it is less dehydrating than sulfuric acid. In the formation of acetals, water is being formed as a product, thus dehydrating effects of the acid would be productive. In this case, it would not make a difference since I am using a water separator, but still I am wondering why dehydrating effects of the acid are not desired.

Is there any other reason I am missing? If so, I would also be happy about literature references.

Comment: *p*TsOH is better soluble in organic solvents than sulfuric acid, and not as strong dehydrating than sulfuric acid. Do you recall sulfuric acid's action on sugar [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOedJgqTT9E)?  Thus it is better to have some *p*TsOH well dissolved in the reaction mixture remove the water by Dean-Stark distillation. See if your school has access to Paquette's [enyclopedia](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Encyclopedia+of+Reagents+for+Organic+Synthesis%2C+14+Volume+Set%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470017548) (there is an online-version, too [campus license?]) and continue from there.